# ImportError for existing module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I'm trying to import a series of modules into my Python 3.5 code. I use the following code to import:

```
# import packages for analysis and modeling
import pandas as pd  # data frame operations; use pandas 0.18
from pandas.tools.rplot import RPlot, TrellisGrid, GeomPoint, \
ScaleRandomColour  # trellis/lattice plotting
import numpy as np  # arrays and math functions
from scipy.stats import uniform  # for training-and-test split
import statsmodels.api as sm  # statistical models (including regression)
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf  # R-like model specification
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # 2D plotting
```

When i use this code, I receive the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/zy/snhf2bh51v33ny6nf7fyr4wh0000gn/T/tmpdxMQ0Y.py in <module>()
      7 # import packages for analysis and modeling
      8 import pandas as pd  # data frame operations; use pandas 0.18
----> 9 from pandas.tools.rplot import RPlot, TrellisGrid, GeomPoint, \
     10     ScaleRandomColour  # trellis/lattice plotting
     11 import numpy as np  # arrays and math functions
ImportError: No module named 'pandas.tools.rplot'
```

I tried this code with "pd" and with "pandas" written out. I confirmed that pandas was installed by manually typing in `import pandas as pd` and then confirming its existence by typing in "pd" and receiving the following message: `<module 'pandas' from '/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy/edm/envs/User/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>`

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: The code listed in the traceback does not match the code at the start of the question.

Comment: My apologies, I reran the original code and copy-pasted it above in an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming it during `import` with `as` doesn't mean Python will be able to  find the original module (`pandas`) when you use the name `pd` at a later import statement. Python will look for a module named `pd` which it will not find.

Since `pd` does not correspond to some module while `pandas` does, you'll need to use `from pandas import tools` in order to get it to work.

Comment: I had tried it with both, and the same error occurred: `Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-1f5a46b0c433>", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.tools.rplot import RPlot, TrellisGrid, GeomPoint,     ScaleRandomColour  # trellis/lattice plotting

ImportError: No module named 'pandas.tools.rplot'`

Comment: @Yehuda What version of pandas do you run? It seems that package isn't available anymore, however, your original question has been addressed sufficiently.

Comment: My package manager says I'm running 0.19.2-4, which it says is the most up-to-date version.